# I can't query a table without primary key

Tags: python, html, django

I'm trying to query through a model in Django that has no `Primary Key`.
I need to query though it so I can access to the `Foreign keys` it has.

I'm just trying to do this atm and doesn't even work:

```
chars = Characterweapons.objects.all()

print(chars)
```

And if i change `Characterweapons` to `Weapons` for example, a table with Primary Key it works.

The error I get when I load the page is this:

```
Exception Value: (1054, "Unknown column 'characterweapons.id' in 'field list'")
```

This is my model:

```
class Characterweapons(models.Model):
    characterid = models.ForeignKey(Characters, models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='CharacterID')  # Field name made lowercase.
    weaponid = models.ForeignKey(Weapons, models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='WeaponID', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    categoryid = models.ForeignKey(Category, models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='CategoryID', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    quantity = models.IntegerField(db_column='Quantity', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'characterweapons'

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s %s %s %s' % (self.quantity,self.characterid,self.weaponid,self.categoryid)
```

Anyone knows about this?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Well in your Django table, you have implicitly a column named `id` that is the primary key, *unless* you specify the primary key somewhere else. Since Django build queries, it assumes there is an `id` column, and thus queries with it.

Comment: Have you created your own migrations? As per [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/options/#django.db.models.Options.managed) when you have managed=False there'll be no DB migrations and that could be the case.

Comment: Have you looked at the sql that Django uses? (I just published a middleware to do this: https://pypi.org/project/django-sqlprint-middleware/0.1.0/)

Comment: @thebjorn very nice, I just installed it. Do you have any guide for it?

Comment: It's all in the README, just install it, add it to your middleware and manage.py runserver. The sql will show up in the runserver terminal.

Comment: Sorry, just realized that Django changed its middleware system. I've uploaded a new version to PyPI that should work for both new and old Djangos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it looks like you did a DBinspect on an existing database to generate this model. I'm guessing this is failing because Django ORM expects your table to have a primary key. "id" is the default name for a Django generated model primary key field. I suspect when you are trying to call `Characterweapons.objects.all()` it's trying to get the primary key field for some reason.

There may be a workaround but unless you *really* know what your doing with your database, I would highly urge you to set a primary key on your tables.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution that I found, in this case, was to perform my own query, for example:

```
fact = MyModelWithoutPK.objects.raw("SELECT * FROM my_model_without_pk WHERE my_search=some_search")
```

This way you don't have to implement or add another middleware.
see more at [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/sql/)